# Why is scala.math.PartialOrdering.lteq abstract, rather than defined in terms of .tryCompare?

Tags: scala, partial-ordering

It seems that [`scala.math.PartialOrdering.lteq`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/math/PartialOrdering.scala#L58) must always be defined as (or at least, give the same result as):

```
override def lteq(x: Pattern, y: Pattern) = {
    tryCompare(x, y).map(_ <= 0).getOrElse(false)
}
```

Is there some reason this implementation isn't given in the `scala.math.PartialOrdering` trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is to encourage writing a more efficient `lteq`, as all other methods fall back to `lteq`. So you wouldn't want to create an `Option`, then map it. I would rather ask the opposite -- why isn't `tryCompare` implemented by default, e.g.:

```
def tryCompare(x: T, y: T) = {
  val p1 = lteq(x, y)
  val p2 = lteq(y, x)
  if (p1) {
    if(p2) Some(0) else Some(-1)
  } else if (p2) Some(1) else None
}
```

...and you wouldn't need to write the ugly `override` modifier when implementing `lteq`.

As far as I can see `tryCompare` is never ever used within the whole Scala standard library body, so maybe it's just a 'left-over'...

Comment: From a mathematician's (that's me!) point of view, somehow it feels nicer to leave `tryCompare` unimplemented, but agree that if you're encouraging people to write optimized code then `lteq` is a better override candidate.